# Find the projection P_M (x,y)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let M = {(z,3z) : x∈R} be a subspace of, and P_M :R² -> M denote the projection on M. 
The projection P_M (x,y) is a point in M such that 
||(x,y) - P_M (x,y)|| = min √((x-z)²+(y-3z)²). Find the projection P_M (x,y)

Not sure where to start with this question. I think you can use gram-schmidt orthogonal process but unsure of how. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with complex-analysis and very little to do with real-analysis. (More linear-algebra. I have retagged it for you.)

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that, as the name (as well as the definition) suggests, that for any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, its projection on $M$, i.e., $P_M(x,y)$ is the vector on $M$ such that the distance $\|(x,y)-P_M(x,y)\|$ is minimized. Geometrically, $P_M(x,y)$ will be the point on $M$ obtained by dropping perpendicular to $M$ from the point $(x,y)$.

Now notice that $M$ is nothing but the straight line, with slope $3$, passing through origin. So, given any point $(x,y)$ write down the equation of a line passing through $(x,y)$ with slope $-\frac{1}{3}$ and find the point of intersection of the two lines. After these calculations the final result will look like
\begin{equation}
P_M(x,y) = \left(\frac{x+3y}{10},3\frac{x+3y}{10}\right)
\end{equation}